# Refactoring a concrete method in abstract class which contains an abstract method

Tags: c#, design-patterns, refactoring, abstract-class

Considering the below code,

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
 public abstract void AbstractMethodA();
 public void ConcreteMethodA()
 {
  //Some operation
  ConcreteMethodB();
 }
}

 public void ConcreteMethodB()
 {
  //Huge code unrelated to this class
  AbstractMethodA();
 }
}

class DerivedClass : AbstractClass
{
public void AbstractMethodA()
{
//Some operation
}
}
```

Now I wish to move ConcreteMethodB() to separate class and make a call to this from the method ConcreteMethodA() in abstract class. But since ConcreteMethodB() uses an abstract method AbstractMethodA() implemented in DerivedClass, I am unable to access the method AbstractMethodA() from the new class? Any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you make it like this

```
static class Helper {
 public static void ConcreteMethodB(AbstractClass caller)
 {
      //Huge code unrelated to this class
      caller.AbstractMethodA();
 }
}
```

and then in AbstractClass

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
 public abstract void AbstractMethodA();
 public void ConcreteMethodA()
 {
  //Some operation
  Helper.ConcreteMethodB(this);
 }
}
```

**Edit including interface based decoupling suggestion from David Arno:**

```
static class Helper {
 public static void ConcreteMethodB(IAbstractClass caller)
 {
      //Huge code unrelated to this class
      caller.AbstractMethodA();
 }
}
interface IAbstractClass {
     void AbstractMethodA();
}
```

and then in AbstractClass

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
 public abstract void AbstractMethodA();
 public void ConcreteMethodA()
 {
  //Some operation
  Helper.ConcreteMethodB(this);
 }
}
```

That gives you better layers isolation. Of course the solution suggested by David in his post mentioning usage of "Action" and passing method as argument is also worth consideration.

Comment: I'd take that one step further and have `ConcreteMethodB(IAbstractClass caller)` and create an interface that `AbstractClass` implements to reduce the coupling.

Comment: @DavidArno sure, I do agree.

Comment: Oh and you need to change `public void ConcreteMethodB...` to `public static void ConcreteMethodB`. I discovered this when checking that my answer (which I copy/pasted/edited from yours) compiled :)

Comment: @user1928158 No I just checked that in my compiler it works fine. Please make sure you added "static" keyword to ConcreteMethodB definition "public static void" it should be. I fixed that several minutes after posting.

Comment: sorry. My bad. Ignore my previous comment. I deleted that almost immediately after posting.

Comment: @user1928158 Sure thanks for the info :) Good to know it works :) please mark as answer if you get it finally working and you like my answer

Answer (score 4):

To completely decouple to the two, you could take the "functional" route:

```
static class Helper 
{
    public static void ConcreteMethodB(Action caller)
    {
        //Huge code unrelated to this class
        caller();
    }
}
```

The change AbstractClass to:

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public abstract void AbstractMethodA();
    public void ConcreteMethodA()
    {
        Helper.ConcreteMethodB(AbstractMethodA);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks much for all the help. I had to try using a custom delegate instead of Action as the real time method had a parameter as well. Is there any better way to do that other than what I tried?

Comment: @user1928158, `Action<T>` may well help you there. It's a built-in delegate for a method `void f(T param)`. Obviously, replace `T` with your parameter's type in this case.

Comment: I think that's a way more elegant solution. Cheers @David Arno.